# headerTitleAlign: 'left', does not work in EXPO with TypeScript Tab Project

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

is my code something wrong?
I just want to　left-justified the header title "RumoR"

I have tried, `textAlign` inside `headrStyle`, and did not work.

```html
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.light.tint
    },
    headerTintColor: Colors.light.background,
    headerTitleAlign: "left",
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: "bold"
    }
  }}
>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Root"
    component={BottomTabNavigator}
    options={{
      headerTitleAlign: "left",
      title: "RumoR"
    }}
  />
  <Stack.Screen
    name="NotFound"
    component={NotFoundScreen}
    options={{ title: "Oops!" }}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>;
```

[Homescreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YOQb.png)

Comment: hello! could you please share the name of the router package you are using?